# Access 2003: Can't get results of command button query to appear in text box on form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have a command button tied to a query called "GenderCount". The results appear in a subtable when I click the button. I need the results to appear in a text box on my form (Text26). Here is my code--thanks in advance for any suggestions:

```
Private Sub Command21_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command21_Click

    Dim stDocName As String

    stDocName = "GenderCount"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit

Exit_Command21_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command21_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command21_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: What are the results of GenderCount? Is it just one record with a value? We need more information and clarity on the following to help: "The results appear in a subtable when I click the button. I need the results"

Comment: Gender CountOfGender M 1483 F 1505 2988 Results appear in tabular form; tried pasting it in but this is how it pasted. It's a total of each value followed by a grand total

Comment: so, which results do you need in the text box? all of them? into one text box?

Comment: It's possible, just not very attractive as user experience. See my answer below and let me know if that works. So you have text fields with labels for Male and Female...

Answer (score 0):

This what you need

```
Private Sub Command21_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command21_Click

    me.txtField1 = dlookup("CountOfGender","GenderCount","Gender = M")
    me.txtField1 = dlookup("CountOfGender","GenderCount","Gender = F")

Exit_Command21_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command21_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command21_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Hmmm...I tried that and it gets stuck on ".txtField1 =" with the error message "Compile error: Method or data member not found"

Comment: First thing I recommend is reading up on Access VBA... There is a tremendous amount on the web for learning what you are trying to accomplish. That is how I learned! That said, you you need to add two text fields into your form and call them txtField1 and txtField2, or whatever, just make sure the name matches.